# How to download specific sheet from tableau dashboard using python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, tableau-api

I'm trying to download a specific sheet from the following website using python:

https://public.tableau.com/views/WYCOVID-19Dashboard/WyomingCOVID-19CaseDashboard?:showVizHome=no

I got to know this hack that if we add /CSVDownload.csv before the '?' in the above URL, it downloads a csv with data.
https://public.tableau.com/views/WYCOVID-19Dashboard/WyomingCOVID-19CaseDashboard/CSVDownload.csv?:showVizHome=no

By default tableau server downloads the first sheet available. Is there a way I can add parameters to the URL so that I can download the desired sheet and not the first one by default. it downloads 'case age' sheet from the dashboard and I want 'case map'.

Note: I'm aware of the download option in the right bottom of the workbook and the crosstab option. If there is no work around can we get case map sheet from crosstab using selenium?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you can use [TableauScraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) . Use `setParameter` to select the appropriate filter. disclosure: I'm the author of this lib

Comment: Thanks @BertrandMartel . I was able to develop a script using selenium to download the file.

Comment: Hello, just to let you know I've included the csv download feature in the library: https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping#download-csv-data